# codeigniter Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER form post method

Tags: forms, codeigniter

When using the form with the post method after submit Codeigniter returns the following error

`Message: Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER`

here is my view code

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');
  

 if($this->input->post('username')){ echo 1; }

?>
   
  <form action=""  method="post" >
   
   <input type="hidden" name="csrf_mds_token" value="5fec4b5ddafa0921751171a32aea45d8">
   
  <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control auth-form-input" >
  
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-custom btn-block">submit</button>
  
 </form>
```

I want the user to be redirected to an external site after clicking on the button, but after clicking, it gives an error

`Message: Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER`

Comment: The code you posted isn't quite enough for us to see what's causing the issue. It might be that the rest of your code is relying on `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, which is not set within the `$_SERVER` superglobal variable.

Comment: @FiddlingAway I changed the codes